# Saving DateTime with WebMatrix and Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, webmatrix, sql-server-ce-4

I am developing a project that has a DateTime field.

In it I'm using jQuery for the user to select the date format 'dd/MM/yyyy' taking into account that the date is not a required field.

**How do you do to save DateTime fields not required in WebMatrix and Razor?**

I was trying to do something like this:

> I put only the code which I think is
>   important to complete the code can be
>   found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Riderman/JV5gD/)

```
@{
//Get data
string TaskForecastCompletion= Request["txtForecastCompletion"];
string TaskCompletedIn= Request["txtCompletedIn"];

                    DateTime dtForecastCompletion = default(DateTime);
                    if (!Request["txtForecastCompletion"].IsEmpty() && !DateTime.TryParse(Request["txtForecastCompletion"], out dtForecastCompletion))
                    {
                            ModelState.AddError("PrevisaoFinalizacao", "Data de previsão de finalização é inválida. Formato: dd/mm/aaaa");
                    }


                                    sql = @"update Tasks set Title = @0 ,Description = @1 ,ProjectID = @2 ,ForecastCompletion = @3 ,RequestBy = @4 ,CompletedIn = @5 ,Modified = getdate() ,Priority = @6 where ID = @7";
                                    db.Execute(sql, TaskTitle,TaskDescription, ProjectID, dtForecastCompletion, TaskRequestBy, dtTaskCompletedIn, TaskPriority, TaskID);
}
```

**Error trying to change**

> An overflow occurred while converting
>   to datetime.  Description: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during
>   the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error
>   and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException:
>   An overflow occurred while converting
>   to datetime.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 62:                         {
>   Line 63:
>   sql = @"update Tasks set Title = @0
>   ,Description = @1 ,ProjectID = @2
>   ,ForecastCompletion = @3 ,RequestBy =
>   @4 ,CompletedIn = @5 ,Modified =
>   getdate() ,Priority = @6 where ID =
>   @7"; Line 64:
>   db.Execute(sql,
>   TaskTitle,TaskDescription, ProjectID,
>   dtForecastCompletion, TaskRequestBy,
>   dtTaskCompletedIn, TaskPriority,
>   TaskID); Line 65:
>   } Line 66:

Comment: Please post the error in a code block without killing the newlines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your date field in the database is nullable (not marked as NOT NULL), you can change your datatype in C# to a [nullable DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
 DateTime? dtForecastComplete = null;
```

Now you can pass (and retrieve) a null value to/from the database.

Comment: In my code I use TryParse DateTime class and it does not accept nullable.

See how it changed the code in this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Riderman/JV5gD/). Just put the save. **Error:** "An overflow occurred while converting to datetime. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of 
overflow occurred while converting to datetime."

Comment: I added an auxiliary variable in order to use TryParse still the error occurs above.

Comment: Those are the problems i mentioned below. You have to alter your entire project if you have not used the nullable DateTime in the beginning. That's why in most cases a "Quick And Dirty" solution is a nice timesaving workaround.

Comment: This project is only for study, has a few pages.
Change the entire project is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted a "Quick And Dirty" solution, i would insert the `DateTime.MinValue` as initial value, and test on that when displaying it again to make it empty.

Of course, a better way is to dynamically build your insert statement and value list, to exclude it from the list if the value is empty.

Comment: there is some way to put null instead of Min?

Comment: GvS answered that for you ;-)  Make sure that you change the DataType of the DateTime field throughout your whole application though, or you will have Build errors.

Comment: Using the conversion: "db.Execute (sql paramters {}"

Comment: What does riding a query with one of the fields in brackets '[' ']'.
Example:  var db = UserHelper.DatabaseInstance;
         db.query (@ "INSERT INTO Events
                     (OrganizerId, CalendarId, Name, Description, Location, AllDay, Start, [End])
              Values (@ 0, @ 1, @ 2, @ 3, @ 4, @ 5, @ 6, @ 7) ",
                     userId, calendarId, name, description, location, allday, utcStart, utcEnd);